# avoiding code duplication for Properties in PySide2

Tags: python, qml, pyside2, python-descriptors

I am tired of writing the same code for declaring `Properties` for `PySide2`:

```
class BackEnd(QObject):

    my_prop_updated = Signal()

    @Property(bool)
    def my_prop(self):
        print('getter invoked'))
        return self._my_prop

    @my_prop.setter
    def set_my_prop(self, value):
        print('setter invoked')
        self._my_prop = value
        self.my_prop_updated.emit()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._my_prop = None
```

Is there any way to make use of python descriptors with `Properties`? Something like so:

```
class QTPropBool(Property):
    my_prop_updated = Signal()

    def my_getter(self, obj):
        print('getter invoked')
        return self._my_prop

    def my_setter(self, obj, value):
        print('setter invoked')
        self._my_prop = value
        self.my_prop_updated.emit()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(bool, self.my_getter, self.my_setter, notify=self.my_prop_updated)


class BackEnd(QObject):
    my_prop = QTPropBool()
```

It gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: 'PySide2.QtCore.Signal' object has no attribute 'emit'
```

Probably because it's `Property` class, not `QObject` and I am not invoking `QObject`'s constructor. Is there any way to avoid code duplication?

Comment: Why are you writing so many properties? What's the context?

Comment: I have many text fields in my QML and they are set/updated through Python backend which talks to hardware

Comment: @Artem 
mark as a duplicate your question because the code is similar, except for the PyQt5 to PySide conversions, if you can not do it the translation is in the following link: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/21e1739e25daffb98e4a7d1fad826096